# vscode debugger unexpected toke 'import'

Tags: mysql, node.js, debugging, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I am new to nodejs and vscode...... I have two files: `entry.js` and `/utils/database.js`.

When I run `node entry.js` I get the little logging that I expect(`SSSS`). I would like to run this in debug mode so that I can build on it but when I click on the "Run" in debug on the left side I get:

> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
> ```

---

- **System:** Ubuntu 18.04
- **Editor:** Visual Studio Code version 1.45.1
- `node --version`: v13.11.0
- `npm --version`: 6.13.7

---

**package.json:**

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "node_load_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  }
}
```

**launch.json:**

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch root Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/entry.js"
    },
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch 6 Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/6/entry.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

**utils/database.js:**

```
import mysql from "mysql";

export const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "no_replicate",
});
```

**entry.js:**

```
"use strict";

import { pool } from "./utils/database.js";

pool.end(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("error:" + err.message);
  }
  console.log("Close the database connection.");
});

pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
  // execute query
  // ...
  console.log("SSSS");
});
```

Any help would make my day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in utils/database.js:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: 100,
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "no_replicate",
});
module.exports = pool
```

in entry.js

```
const pool = require('./utils/database.js');

pool.end(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log("error:" + err.message);
  }
  console.log("Close the database connection.");
});

pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
  // execute query
  // ...
  console.log("SSSS");
});
```

and in Nodejs we import like with require('package-name')

Comment: I do not want to use old-style require. I am using es-6 syntax

Comment: you can use this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm/v/3.2.25 to allow you to run es6 syntax

Comment: I cannot see how this will change my issue? When i run the limited app from the terminal I do get the expected response of "SSSS" so my module import syntax is correct. It is when I try to debug the app that it blows up in my face.

Comment: https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-debug-es6-nodejs-with-vscode-8d00bd6c4f94